# Office 365 management activity api sample code and pricing

Tags: office365, office365api, office365connectors

I am currently developing an native client application using Office 365 Managed Activity.I am having office 365 subscription.Is there any fees applicable for using it.Also I found some link.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/api-management/
Is this applicable for management activity api.

Also can I find sample code of managed activity api using c#

Answer (score 0):

Check this Office365APIEditor sample available on GitHub here: [Office365APIEditor on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Office365APIEditor)